# Nasty interaction between ASP.NET MVC Routing and my login system

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC application that has two kind of pages: (1) a login page, and (2) everything else. Even my home page displays content that requires authorized access:

```
public class HomeController : Controller {
    [CustomAuthorize] // My custom authorization tag
    public ActionResult Index() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

But now I have the following "little" problem. When I navigate to `http://my-site/`, the following sequence of events takes place:

1. Since no controller and no action were specified, the default values ("Home" and "Index", respectively) are used.
2. Since `HomeController.Index()` has the `CustomAuthorizeAttribute` attribute, then I get redirected to my login page.
3. My login page attempts to load, among other things `http://my-site/Content/Site.css`.
4. In this new request, since there is no controller called `ContentController`, ASP.NET processes the request as if `Content` and `Site.css` were parameters of a request to `http://my-site/`. Which, of course, requires authentication, and...

Is there any way to make ASP.NET MVC Routing process requests to `http://my-site/Content/*` or `http://my-site/Scripts/*` differently than other requests?

---

**EDIT:** Here is my `global.asax` file:

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication {
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters) {
        filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
    }

    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes) {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
    }

    private void Application_Start() {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the default route the only route you use? Check (and show us, if not) your global.asax.cs file

Comment: @David: Yes, I am using the default routing. // I will post my `global.asax` anyway.

Comment: @Eduardo I realize you didn't tag the question MVC3, but are you using 3? I could suggest a global filter if you are

Comment: I think you're mis-diagnosing the problem, #4 is probably not true. If the path matches a physical file on disk, IIS will get it completely outside of the MVC pipeline. Something else is going on, probably in code you're not showing us.

Comment: @David: Yes, I am using MVC3. // @Gabe: I am not sure what else the problem could be. I am going to try including scripts using `src="/Scripts/..."` instead of `src="@Url.Content(...)"`.

Comment: What is really strange is that, when I run the site on ASP.NET Development Server, I don't get any errors. When I run the site on IIS, I get all sorts of errors.

Comment: @Eduardo - as far as the Cassini server is concerned, you are authorized (using Windows authentication).  Your app likely does forms-based so it doesn't recognize it, but the web.config based authorization will take it into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have access restrictions in your web.config?  If so, you shouldn't.  Typically in an MVC app, you handle that entirely with attributes.  I think if actual files exist on disk at the path the request won't even be routed through MVC.  Given your description it seems most likely that your web.config is set up to deny access to unauthenticated users and that should be removed.

Comment: @tvanfosson: I do not explicitly deny all access to unauthenticated useres in my `Web.config` file, perhaps that is the default. In fact, I would like to allow access to the contents of the `/Contents` and `/Scripts` subfolders, regardless of whether the user is authenticated or not. How do I do that?

Comment: @Eduardo - what do your authorization and authentication sections look like in your web.config, if you have them?

Comment: @tvanfosson: There is no authorization section. The authentication section is: `<authentication mode="Forms"><forms loginUrl="~/Login" timeout="2880" cookieless="UseCookies"/></authentication>`.

Comment: @Eduardo - is it possible you are inheriting web config settings from a parent site?

Comment: @tvanfosson: There is no parent site.

Comment: @Eduardo -- hmmm. not sure where to go next.  IIS7 or IIS6?

Comment: @Eduardo - I can only tell you that I do not see this behavior in my projects under similar configurations.  You might want to investigate the IIS set up more as it really should not be denying access to items in content and scripts under your configuration.

Comment: @tvanfosson: I believe that IIS 7 interprets the authentication section as "access to any file in this web site requires user authentication". How do I limit the scope of user authentication?

Comment: @Eduardo - I'm using IIS7.5 with ASP.NET MVC3 and .NET 4 in the same scenario as you describe and haven't had to do anything special to allow access to content and scripts.  I don't recall having to do anything for earlier versions either, including with IIS6.  If I look at one of my sites in IIS7.5, the .NET Authorization Rules are set as "Allow All Users" -- you might want to check to make sure yours is the same.

Comment: @tvanfosson: Same here (I mean, ".NET Authorization Rules --> Allow All Users"). Maybe I messed up with the `Web.config` file. I am going to copy a new project's config file to my Web app.